# Javascript innerHTML default

Tags: javascript, default, innerhtml

This is not a problem that requires a solution.

But I just found out that Javascript's innerHTML works even without specifying which ID or class I want to work with, if the name is the same as the ID's name.

For example:

Let's say in the HTML, I have: `<div id="input">`

Then in the Javascript, I have: `input.innerHTML = "EMPTY";`

It will work as if I had typed: `document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = "EMPTY";`

How does this work? Does innerHTML have a "default" getElementById thing?

Comment: The `.innerHTML` property is a DOM thing, and is not really a JavaScript thing. It's *usable* from JavaScript, of course.

Comment: ... and browsers create global symbols to correspond with elements in the DOM that have "id" properties. It used to be an IE-only thing, but lately all of them have started doing it. That behavior has nothing specifically to do with `.innerHTML`.

Comment: You probably mean works as `document.getElementById('input')`, not `button`.